# Unable to switch text fonts in LilyPond

Tags: software, lilypond

I've followed all the instructions to set custom fonts in LilyPond and nothing seems to be working. I was originally attempting to set IM Fell English Pro as the document font, but I've set everything to Times New Roman as a control and it still displays the default font.

[Here](http://lilybin.com/acuo9t/1) is the file I'm attempting to engrave, hosted at LilyBin.

I have attempted it with versions `2.18.2` and `2.19.46` and neither of them seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

The `#(set-global-staff-size 14)` you have as the very last line of your file is causing the problems. Moving this to the beginning (I put it in the line right below where you define the paper size) fixes the problem on my end.